# Mapping checkboxes to a model in Angular 5

Tags: angular

I have an angular 5 form that I'm struggling to map checkboxes to.

This is my html for my form component:

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Title</label>
      <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" minlength="2" required maxlength="30" autocomplete="off" id="title"
        #title="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="step1.title">
      <div *ngIf="title.invalid && f.submitted" class="text-danger">
        Promotion title is required and must be between 2 and 30 characters long.

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Pick one or more categories for your promotion</label>
      <div class="form-check" *ngFor="let topic of topics">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" name="topicgroup" id="{{topic.name}}">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1" style="font-weight: normal">
          {{topic.name}}
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I have 2 models in my component, one of Promotions which is what the form is for, and the other for topics.

I have a network service that retrieves a list of topics.

What I would like, is for when the form is submitted, to add them to the Promotion model:

```
export class Promotion {
    title: string;
    topics: string[];
}

export class Topic {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

Currently the list of topics is displayed in my form as a series of checkboxes - not sure how to take the submitted data and save it to the topics[] array on the promotion model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add change Event in your input element

```
 <div class="form-group">
  <label>Pick one or more categories for your promotion</label>
  <div class="form-check" *ngFor="let topic of topics">
    <input (change)="onChange(f)" #f  class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [value]="topic" name="topicgroup" id="{{topic}}">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1" style="font-weight: normal">
      {{topic}}
    </label>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="save">
</div>
```

check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dx2gjf?file=app%2Fapp.component.html